# screen flickering issue when I go full screen in virtualbox or teamviewer

Tags: 21.10

I am having this issue(screen flickering) when I go to full screen with VirtualBox: https://youtu.be/7Vo5L7SJrqc

I use a video because it is the most easy form to show my issue, because it's related to video. That happens when I go full screen from my host OS (Ubuntu) to my virtual machine.

it's happening too when I go full screen in teamviewer session

```
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB<br>
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz<br>
Memory: 16 GB RAM (15.95 GB RAM usable)<br>
Screen Resolution: 1920 x 1080, 60Hz<br>
  System:
        Host: Inspiron-5577 
      Kernel: 5.13.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 
  Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri)
 Machine: Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 5577 v: 1.1.2 serial: <superuser required> 
    Mobo: Dell model: 090HMC v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.1.2 date: 12/01/2018 
 Battery: ID-1: BAT0 charge: 62.2 Wh (100.0%) condition: 62.2/74.0 Wh (84.1%) 
     CPU: Info: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-7300HQ bits: 64 type: MCP cache: L2: 6 MiB 
   Speed: 1596 MHz min/max: 800/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1596 2: 1600 3: 1600 4: 1600 
Graphics:
    Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel
    Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 470.103.01 
    Device-3: Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo
     Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa
  Resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
      OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're using on the host, as well as any details you can provide about the VM, such as whether Guest Additions have been installed, etc? This will make it easier for people to offer solutions that might solve your issue ‍

Comment: hi @matigo, I have added aditional sysinfo, thnx